# How to add dbms.listQueries() procedure to Neo4j 3.1.3 instance?

Tags: stored-procedures, neo4j

I have run one time-consuming query from Neo4j web UI and accidentally сlosed browser page. Now I know nothing about the query status. In web UI in list **Sample scripts/Common procedures** I've found option `List running queries` which run a script:

```
// List running queries
CALL dbms.listQueries()
```

But the result was:

```
There is no procedure with the name `dbms.listQueries` registered for this database instance. 
Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

I suggest, that this procedure somehow missed from my Neo4j distribution, is it possible to get it's code and add it to my instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have verified this, but if I check https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/query-management/procedures/, it states that these are Neo4j Enterprise Edition features. You are running Neo4j Enterprise Edition ? The error you get is what I get for the Community Edition.

Hope this helps !

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Yes, you right. I'm running Community Edition. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This feature was not available for Community Edition atleast till 3.5.14. Not sure about future versions